# After migration from .NET core 2.2 to .NET 5 the application won't start after deploying to azure app service - startup timeout

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-5.0

I am having the following problem. A while ago I migrated my project from .net core 2.2 to .net 5. Migration itself was no problem, locally everything worked almost out of the box. But then I was facing problems deploying the app into an azure app service. The app wouldn't start up. I was getting start up timeouts. After a while I solved the problem by switching the hosting model to outOfProcess

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Because of lack of time to thoroughly test the application, I had to stick with .net 2.2 until now.

Now that I migrated again, I am facing the same issue. Locally everything works just fine, but after deploying to the app service, the application won't start. But the hostingModel doesn't solve it this time.

I tried linux and windows app service, and I tried to deploy via our azure devops pipes as well as manually from VS. I tried to deploy into an existing app service, I tried to deploy into a new app service, created during the deployment process. None of it solves it.

When i look at the log stream, I see the following:

> 2022-02-10T09:13:55.360Z ERROR - Container webapp... for site t2bwebappdev did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.2593377 sec
> 2022-02-10T09:13:55.368Z ERROR - Container webapp... didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

So I tried to solve this via `PORTS` and `WEBSITES_PORT` settings - but non of it seems to get it up and runnig.

Thanks in advance for any hints on how to solve this.

Update:

While I was playing around with the logs, I saw that the app was listening on port 5000. Seems with the Net5 upgrade the launchsettings.json is being ignored.

Then I just dockerized it from VS 2019, and in that container I can also not reach the app. So after all this, could it just be a port issue?

Comment: The default time is 230 seconds for starting the container. To configure , add an app setting called ***WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT*** , set it to the number of seconds you would like it  to wait for your container to start  (up to a maximum of 1800)

Comment: Thanks for the hint - it still fails to startup.

Comment: Do you have the 5.0 library installed on core machine?  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: It's an azure app service, that has as a runtime .NET 5 configured.

Comment: Are you trying to publish as self-contained, single file executable? Because "Apps published as a single file executable can't be loaded by the in-process hosting model." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Shumachine - what is the error you are getting in the Windows App Service , startup ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1003418/azure-docker-app-error-site-did-not-start-within-expected-time-limit-and-co

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I tried to solve it by setting it to OutOfProcess, as mentioned. But it didn't solve it this time. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hi @Shumachine did you tried with no dependencies? I have a feeling in some dependency constructor/injection you are blocking the thread at the startup. Like an HTTP call or some DB roundtrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **this** line in your **Program.cs** class:

[image: Program.cs]

And make sure you expose ports in **Dockerfile**:

[image: Dockerfile]

**NOTE:**

Everything depends on which port was exposed in **Dockerfile**.
Port that you have exposed should match with the port you will pass to **UseUrls** as an argument. Also, consider either **http/https** in accordance with the existence of the certificate.

I hope my answer was useful and helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly where the problem was located. The problem emerged because the ports are exposed differently from 2.2 to 5 and up. So after we exposed the ports in the app, and then mapped the ports in the docker file, everything worked.
In addition: When you deploy into an Azure AppService (which basically abstracts the docker underneath, you have to configure the ports in the appService.

Thanks for the help!